# Python re.findall returning only first character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

Working in Python 3.6, I have a list of html files with date prefixes. I'd like to return all dates, so I join the list and use some regex, like so:

```
import re
snapshots =  ['20180614_SII.html', '20180615_SII.html']
p = re.compile("(\d|^)\d*(?=_)")
snapshot_dates = p.findall(' '.join(snapshots))
```

`snapshot_dates` is a list, `['2', '2']`, but I'm expecting `['20180614', '20180615']`. Demonstration here: https://regexr.com/3r44o. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try: `p = re.compile(r"\d*(?=_)")`? The problem with your is that you create a group with the first parenthesis.  Probably even something like `r"(:?\d|^)\d*(?=_)"` should work.

Comment: your regex is weird. parentheses mean "catch" and yes you're only catching one digit (it's the `\d*` part that does the matching and should be in parentheses). the simplest regex here would be `(\d*)_SII.html` but as pault indicates, no regex at all is even better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your pattern to use `\d+` instead of `(\d|^)\d*`:

```
p = re.compile("\d+(?=_)")
print(p.findall(' '.join(snapshots)))
#['20180614', '20180615']
```

However, in this case you may not need `regex` to achieve the desired result. You can instead just split the string on `_`:

```
print([x.split("_")[0] for x in snapshots])
#['20180614', '20180615']
```